# Is there a ranged pull for Guardians?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I just started playing Lord of the Rings Online as a Guardian, and I've noticed I don't have the ability to use any ranged weapons (bows, etc).  Is it possible for me to do a ranged pull at all, or am I forced to charge in and start swinging?

Answer (score 3):

While you do get Bows at level 30 (champions get it at level 18) there is another way: Throwing Axes.

Throwing Axes are crafted by weaponsmiths (not sure if you can buy it from vendors) and deal much, much, much less damage then a bow. You also only have a finite number, but it is a good way to pull mobs before level 30

They are also available for every class, so if you have other characters that are melee-only you may want to get some.

Answer (score 2):

You should get a bow ability at level 30. No auto-shoot like the hunters have, but you'll be able to make the single-shot required to pull.

Comment: You can still auto attack with the bow as a guardian.